# Coset of the Abstract index group of a Banach Algebra?

Tags: group-theory, homotopy-theory, banach-algebras

I'm studying on the book of Douglas: "Banach algebra techniques in operator theory" and there is a passage I don't understand, and I hope you can give me a hand.

"A continuous function $f$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{T}$ (the circle group) determines first an element $\{f\}$ of $\pi^1(X)$ (the group of homotopy classes of continuous maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{T}$) and second, viewed as an invertible function on $X$, determines a coset $f + G_0$ of $\Lambda$.  ($G_0$ is the connected component of the invertible functions that contains the $\mathbb{1}$ function and $\Lambda$ is the abstract index group for $C(X)$.)"

The part that I don't understand is the "coset $f + G_0$ of $\Lambda$."

$\Lambda$ is a group, not a subgroup (or is the subgroup of itself but this case is irrelevant.)
The cosets are sets of the form: $element\ of \ the \ group(SUBGROUP)$. How can  $f + G_0$ be a coset?

Please, try to clarify to me in what sense  $f + G_0$ is a coset of $\Lambda$.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe the group operation for $\Lambda$ is the addition? In that case $G_0$ can be considered a subgroup of $\Lambda$ in the sense that $G_0^{-1}$ is $G_0$ and $G_0^2$ is $G_0$. But then the cosets should be of the form $(element \ of \ \Lambda) + (G_0)$, not $f + G_0$... And anything about this group operation on $\Lambda$ is mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: If $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{T}$ is the function $f(x) = -1$ for all $x$, then the set $f + G_0$ is not even invertible because it contains the element $\mathbb{0}$ ... I really don't understand this passage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f + G_0$ is intended as $fG_0$ everything does make sense, because this is an element of $\Lambda$. But it's not an orthographic error because this notation it's repeated in all the theorem, and the cosets of $G_0$ are denoted, as normal, with the notation $fG_0$ earlier in the book. I judge this a very bad choice of notation... :-(